# Angular 6 - browser-crypto.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular6

I am implementing socketjs. however i have encountered below error.

[image: Angular 6 Socket Error] Below are the socket and stomp packages which i am using.

```
import * as SockJS from 'sockjs-client';
import * as Stomp from 'stompjs/lib/stomp.js';
```

Thanks in Advance.

Here is my angular code-

```
import * as Socket from 'socket.io-client';
import * as Stomp from 'stompjs/lib/stomp.js';

initializeWebSocketConnection2(){

let ws = new Socket(this.serverUrl);

this.stompClient = Stomp.over(ws);
let that = this;
this.stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {


   that.stompClient.subscribe("/test", function(message){ 
        if(message.body) {
          console.log(message.body);
         window.location.reload(); 
        }
 });


   that.stompClient.subscribe("/operation", function(message){ 
        if(message.body) {
          console.log(message.body);
          window.location.reload();

        }
 });
```

});

}

Answer (score 17):

Add this in your polyfills.ts

```
(window as any).global = window
```

First you need to install socket-client with typing

```
npm install --save @types/socket.io
```

Then you can import the socket.io-client in your component or service like this

```
import * as Socket from 'socket.io-client';
```

Change your code like this

```
let ws = Socket(this.serverUrl);
```

Comment: @Challappan -  Same error Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at Object../node_modules/socket.io-parser/binary.js (binary.js:10)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
    at Object../node_modules/socket.io-parser/index.js (index.js:9)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
    at Object../node_modules/socket.io-client/lib/index.js (index.js:7)

Comment: (window as any).global = window; add this in your code and check now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176147/discussion-between-unicorn-and-chellappan).

Comment: `window as any).global = window;` in polyfills.ts solved the issue to me https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8160#issuecomment-386153833

Comment: (window as any).global = window; at the bottom of my polyfill.ts fixed my occurance of this issue also, thanks !

Comment: Here is polyfill.ts located or how do I create it?

Comment: It will be under src folder. If not present check angular documentation for how to config one:https://angular.io/guide/browser-support#enabling-polyfills-with-cli-projects @ajheath

Answer (score 17):

Adding the following snippet in the *head* of index.html resolved the issue in my case -

```
<script type="application/javascript">
  var global = window;
</script>
```

Ref. https://github.com/stomp-js/ng2-stompjs/issues/70

Answer (score 2):

adding following code works for me

```
  <script>
      var global = window; // fix global is undefined in socketjs-client
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Solve this problem using use built version

```
import sockjs from "sockjs-client/dist/sockjs"
```