# Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined

Tags: angular

Hello I'm trying to use stomp in angular. once i use it in my project I lost my whole project , I get white page nothing is working.

```
this.stompService.subscribe('/topic/vehicle', (): void => {
  this.getnotificationsByReceiver();
});
```

please can't understand what is this. I tried many times same issue

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51380166/angular-6-browser-crypto-js3-uncaught-referenceerror-global-is-not-defined/51380307).

The global object is not available. Possible solution to change it to window object.