# Angular Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined when importing awc-sdk

Tags: angular, angularjs, amazon-web-services, sdk

Im using angular 15, and this is my code, importing aws-sdk client.

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk'//connect to sqs

 
const sqs = new AWS.SQS({
  region: 'us-east-1',
  accessKeyId: 'mykey',
  secretAccessKey: 'my secretkey'
});
```

I have the same error like in this topic: [Angular 6 - browser-crypto.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51380166/angular-6-browser-crypto-js3-uncaught-referenceerror-global-is-not-defined/51380307)

The topic propose to add

```
(window as any).global = window
```

into polyfills.ts.

But current angular version does not contain polyfills.ts.

so I tried:

1)create polyfills.ts in the src directory and add the proposed code to it

2. add `(window as any).global = window` in the main.ts
3. add

```
 <script type="application/javascript">
  let global = window;
</script>
```

in index.html

but none of these works, i still receive a white screen in the browser and the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined" in the console.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Angular 15 does not create polyfills.ts file, so

1. create the file src/polyfills.ts
2. add the following to polyfills.ts

```js
(window as any).global = window
```

3. add the polyfills.ts reference to tsconfig.app.json in the files section

```js
 "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
```

4. restart the server

Answer (score 0):

you can use aws cdn instead of sdk to make it available globally
here is how I have done it for my project

index.html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aws-sdk/2.1578.0/aws-sdk.min.js"></script>
```

app.component.ts

```
declare var AWS: any; // Declare AWS as any type
const accessKeyId = "";
const secretAccessKey = "";
```

use AfterViewInit Hook

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    AWS.config.update({
      accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey,
      region: 'us-east-1'
    });
    console.log('AWS Configured', AWS.config);

  }
```